Solana - Rust, Error Number: 4100 - The declared program id does not match the actual program id
I have this simple smart contract in Rust for Solana. When I run the tests, I encounter this error as if the wrong program_id was inserted. Can you tell me what I’m doing wrong? Thanks
The encountered error:
Transaction failed: { [Error: failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: custom program error: 0x1004]
  logs: 
   [ 'Program HsNN2hb3pUkdwpQfjG3xoiuNcBZEbidcdzF8TxXUoJG5 invoke [1]',
     'Program log: AnchorError occurred. Error Code: DeclaredProgramIdMismatch. Error Number: 4100. Error Message: The declared program id does not match the actual program id.',
     'Program HsNN2hb3pUkdwpQfjG3xoiuNcBZEbidcdzF8TxXUoJG5 consumed 2190 of 200000 compute units',
     'Program HsNN2hb3pUkdwpQfjG3xoiuNcBZEbidcdzF8TxXUoJG5 failed: custom program error: 0x1004' ] }

smart contract in Rust:
use anchor_lang::prelude::*;

declare_id!("HsNN2hb3pUkdwpQfjG3xoiuNcBZEbidcdzF8TxXUoJG5");

#[program]
pub mod text_on_blockchain {
    use super::*;

    pub fn initialize(ctx: Context<Initialize>) -> Result<()> {
        let text_account = &mut ctx.accounts.text_account;
        text_account.text = "Hello, Solana!".to_string();
        Ok(())
    }

    pub fn set_text(ctx: Context<SetText>, new_text: String) -> Result<()> {
        let text_account = &mut ctx.accounts.text_account;
        text_account.text = new_text;
        Ok(())
    }

    pub fn get_text(ctx: Context<GetText>) -> Result<String> {
        let text_account = &ctx.accounts.text_account;
        Ok(text_account.text.clone())
    }
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct Initialize<'info> {
    #[account(init, payer = user, space = 8 + 1024)]
    pub text_account: Account<'info, Text>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub user: Signer<'info>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct SetText<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub text_account: Account<'info, Text>,
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct GetText<'info> {
    pub text_account: Account<'info, Text>,
}

#[account]
pub struct Text {
    pub text: String,
}

in Javascript:
import {
  Connection,
  Keypair,
  Transaction,
  TransactionInstruction,
  SystemProgram,
  sendAndConfirmTransaction,
  PublicKey,
} from "@solana/web3.js";
import { serialize, deserialize } from "borsh";

class Text {
  text: string;

  constructor(text: string) {
    this.text = text;
  }
}

const TextSchema = new Map([
  [Text, { kind: "struct", fields: [["text", "string"]] }],
]);

const connection = new Connection("https://api.devnet.solana.com", "confirmed");

const PROGRAM_ID = new PublicKey(
  "HsNN2hb3pUkdwpQfjG3xoiuNcBZEbidcdzF8TxXUoJG5"
);
const text_account_keypair = new Keypair();
const TEXT_ACCOUNT_PUBLIC_KEY = new PublicKey(
  "7pVtBvuZLEwpdYnpGo3QKkgvkMsiwXw7ynqcv2K9WL23"
);

const PAYER_KEYPAIR = Keypair.fromSecretKey(
  new Uint8Array([
    87, 10, 41, 37, 202, 102, 232, 164, 63, 62, 167, 156, 86, 133, 130, 125, 66,
    163, 89, 68, 167, 75, 139, 8, 244, 110, 161, 75, 47, 250, 93, 151, 21, 133,
    66, 201, 43, 200, 125, 51, 114, 245, 48, 220, 114, 213, 179, 134, 240, 1,
    55, 30, 2, 175, 53, 22, 156, 92, 241, 132, 107, 175, 189, 19,
  ])
);

async function initialize() {
  const tx = new Transaction().add(
    SystemProgram.createAccount({
      fromPubkey: PAYER_KEYPAIR.publicKey,
      newAccountPubkey: TEXT_ACCOUNT_PUBLIC_KEY,
      lamports: await connection.getMinimumBalanceForRentExemption(1024),
      space: 1024,
      programId: PROGRAM_ID,
    }),
    new TransactionInstruction({
      keys: [
        { pubkey: TEXT_ACCOUNT_PUBLIC_KEY, isSigner: false, isWritable: true },
      ],
      programId: PROGRAM_ID,
      data: Buffer.from([]), // Empty data for the initialize instruction
    })
  );

  await sendAndConfirmTransaction(connection, tx, [PAYER_KEYPAIR]);
  console.log("Contract initialized");
}

async function setText(newText: string) {
  const text = new Text(newText);
  const serializedData = serialize(TextSchema, text);
  const tx = new Transaction().add(
    new TransactionInstruction({
      keys: [
        { pubkey: TEXT_ACCOUNT_PUBLIC_KEY, isSigner: false, isWritable: true },
      ],
      programId: PROGRAM_ID,
      data: Buffer.from(serializedData), // Serialize the new text
    })
  );

  try {
    await sendAndConfirmTransaction(connection, tx, [PAYER_KEYPAIR]);
    console.log("Text updated to:", newText);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Transaction failed:", error);
  }
}

async function getText() {
  const accountInfo = await connection.getAccountInfo(TEXT_ACCOUNT_PUBLIC_KEY);

  if (accountInfo === null) {
    console.log("Account not found");
    return;
  }

  const text = deserialize(TextSchema, Text, accountInfo.data);

  console.log("Text from blockchain:", text.text);
}

setText("ASDFG");


This error you get when the declared program id in the program does not fit the program address where its deployed. When you do anchor deploy you will get a program id in the console output. This program id you need to copy into the lib.rs file and into your anchor.toml file.
Then afterwards you need to anchor build and anchor deploy again. Then you should not see this error anymore.
